# Properties file (ini file) isn't included in python package

Tags: python, package, pip

How do I include a properties/ini file in a python package that is to be used on both Linux and Windows?

I tried creating a python package by placing the ini file under the Project folder so that I can access it by using code like:

```
File = open("props.ini", 'r')
```

Then I deploy my package into a .tar.gz file as such:

```
$ python setup.py sdist
```

Then I install the package (with a Linux machine):

```
$ sudo pip install package_name.tar.gz
```

I get my .py files here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/package_name/*.py
```

I get my script to open the program here:

```
/usr/local/bin/myScript
```

**But I don't get my .ini file.**

Comment: I also tried :

Adding this line to my setup.py file:

    data_files=[('', ['Project/props.properties'])],

(I hesitate to specify a directory in this line because it would be an issue if someone does not have python 2.7 or is using a non-linux machine)
And that puts my .ini file here:

    /usr/local/props.properties

Since my properties file is not with the rest of my package, my program can't find/access it.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to put your configuration file in a directory under your source code.

For example, if your source code is under `src` directory, you can add your configuration files under `src/config`. After that, for any code in the `src` directory you can access to the config file using:

```
config_filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 
                               'config', <filename>)
```

To maintain the same directory structure when the code is distributed, the `setup` function in `setup.py` needs to know about these new files using the `package_data` argument:

```
setup(
...
package_data={'src': ['config/*',]},
...
)
```

Comment: After reading your comment, I tried doing exactly what you said (with your naming conventions). And then I tried running my program (before creating the package). The result:
IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '.../Project/myFile.py/config/props.ini'

Comment: And of course "myFile.py," "config," and "props.ini" are not directories (and not supposed to be directories). What is os.path.join supposed to do?

Comment: This was much clearer, thanks. Now it worked when I ran the program before I created the package. However, it did not work once I created the package.
My *.py files still go to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/package_name/*.py... so it looks for my .ini file here: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/package_name/config/props.ini ... but my .ini file goes to /usr/local/props.ini

Comment: It works! I followed your instructions again and did it again and it works! Thanks jcollado!

Comment: Eh, so I just checked... And while it works when I install it on Linux, it does not work when I install it on windows. In windows, after I install the package: There is no config directory or .ini file. Also, how do I mark the answer as accepted? I don't have any reputation points so I can't "Vote up"

Comment: @Ari To accept an answer, you don't need to vote it. More information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Anyway, in this case, since the answer isn't completely working for you, don't accept it until someone comes up with a solution that works for you.